# Using Selenium API extension to add command - '(Command) is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, selenium, extension-methods

I'm currently working with the Selenium WebDriver API to develop UI tests for a web app. In my work I've really felt the lack of a "Assert Element Present" type command, after googling this I found an extension somebody had written to add one.

I've integrated this into one of my tests, but when attempting to run the test it throws the error '(Command) is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'. I know this is a pretty common issue for newbies like myself to run into, but I've read many answers to this question and haven't found a single one that applies to me - I really can't see what's wrong here.

Here's my extension:

```
namespace SeleniumTest
{
    public static class WebDriverExtensions 
    {
     public bool IsElementPresent(IWebDriver driver, By locator) //adds 'IsElementPresent' command which asserts presence of element
        {
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(locator);
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000));
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of how I'm attempting to use it in my test case:

```
 [TestFixture]
   public class SeleniumTest
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Login Test"); 
        }


        [TestCase]
        public void LoginTest()
        {
            var IsElementPresent = new WebDriverExtensions.IsElementPresent(By.Id("MainContent_MainContent_Panel_Grids"));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.website.com/account/Login.aspx");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("LoginForm$UserName"));
            query.SendKeys("username");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("LoginForm$Password"));
            query.SendKeys("password");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginForm_Button1"));
            query.Click();

            driver.IsElementPresent(By.Id("MainContent_MainContent_Panel_Grids"));
        }
```

The exact error is:

```
'SeleniumTest.WebDriverExtensions.IsElementPresent(OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, OpenQA.Selenium.By)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type' - Line 55, Column 60
```

All and any advice/help is appreciated, if possible please explain where I'm going wrong as basically as you can - C# is new to me and I'd like to learn from my mistakes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 problems in this code:

1. The class `WebDriverExtensions` is static, and its method `IsElementPresent` is not. All members of a static class must be static too.
2. In the line where you get the error (line 55):
   `var IsElementPresent = new WebDriverExtensions.IsElementPresent(By.Id("MainContent_MainContent_Panel_Grids"));` you should remove the `new` keyword.
3. The method `IsElementPresent` takes 2 arguments - driver and locator, but you only pass the locator.

The best way to fix it is to **make the method `IsElementPresent` an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) by adding the keyword `this` before `IWebDriver`** as in:

`public bool IsElementPresent(this IWebDriver driver, By locator)`
and

and change the calling code to:
`var IsElementPresent = new driver.IsElementPresent(By.Id("MainContent_MainContent_Panel_Grids"));`

Explanation:

The `new` keyword is used only to create an instance (object) of a **non-static** class (static classes can't have instances). Also, if you had to create an instance, then you should have put parenthesis after the class name (e.g. `var IsElementPresent = new WebDriverExtensions().IsElementPresent(...)`) so that it calls the constructor.

With Extension Methods, you pass the first argument (the one that is marked with `this`) as the expression to the left of the dot (`driver` in our case), instead of inside the parenthesis. This is only a syntactic sugar, but it actually behaves exactly like calling the method with 2 argument.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it's been really helpful in my understanding of the issue - however, having implemented your changes to both the extension and the calling code I'm being greeted with a new issue to do with calling .driver (I haven't encountered this anywhere else)

The error ''SeleniumTest.SeleniumTest,driver is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'' is slightly bewildering as I've used several driver. commands that have all been used correctly in this format  in the same scope. Any insight on this?

Comment: You probably didn't removed the 'new' keyword. I guess from the error message that the code you have right now is `var IsElementPresent = new driver() ...`. or something like that. You should change this line to read as follows:
`var IsElementPresent = driver.IsElementPresent(By.Id("MainContent_MainContent_Panel_Grids"));

Comment: aye, see I had it left in as VS complains that IsElementPresent isn't defined in a way that accepts a first argument of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' - but IsElementPresent is defined with the arguments (this IWebDriver driver, By locator) in the line
` public bool IsElementPresent(this IWebDriver driver, By locator)` - but I was able to resolve the issue by making it a public _static_ bool :) thank you for your help!